# remove backslash from a .csv file to load data to redshift from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I am getting an issue when I am loading my file , I have backslash in my csv file
how and what delimited can I use while using my copy command so that I don't get
error loading data from s3 to redshift.
Though I used the QUOTE command but gave me a syntax error so seems like new format
doesn't like the QUOTE key word.
Please if any one can provide a new and correct
command or dow I need to clean or preprocess my data before uploading to s3.
If the
Data size is too big it might not be a very feasible solution

If I have to process it , Do I use pyspark or python(PANDAS) to do it?

Below is the copy command I am using to copy data from s3 to redshift
I tried passing a quote command in the copy command but seems like it doesn't take
that anymore also there is no example in amazon docs on how to do or acheive it

If someone can suggest a command which can replace especial characters while loading
the data

```
COPY redshifttable from 'mys3filelocation'
    CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=myaccess_key;aws_secret_access_key=mysecretID'
    region 'us-west-2'
    CSV
```

DATASET:

```
US063737,2019-11-07T10:23:25.000Z,richardkiganga,536737838,Terminated EOs,"",f,Uganda,Richard,Kiganga,Business owner,Round Planet DTV Uganda,richardkiganga,0.0,4,7.0,2021-06-1918:36:05,"","",panama- 
Disc.s3.amazon.com/photos/…,\"\",Mbale,Wanabwa p/s,Eastern,"","",UACE Certificate,"",drive.google.com/file/d/148dhf89shh499hd9303-JHBn38bh/… phone,Mbale,energy_officer's_id_type,letty 
mainzi,hakuna Cell,Agent,8,"","",4,"","","",+647739975493,Feature phone,"",0,Boda goda,"",1985-10-12,Male,"",johnatlhnaleviski,"",Wife
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible because the `DELIMITER` can only be a single character. Is that the only column that uses quotation marks? Is that column always empty (like the example you have shown us)? If not, then please show additional examples.

Comment: Please put them in your Question, not in a comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein done , please help now

Comment: Sorry, but your formatting of the sample data is bad -- is that all one record, or is it multiple records? There is only one example of backslashes in your sample -- are there other fields with the back-slashes? Are the back-slashes only used in an empty column? What error are you receiving when you load this data? More information please.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have pasted the correct format

Comment: I still can't tell whether that is one line or multiple lines. Also, please answer my earlier questions.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thats a single record. Not multiple lines its a single record

Comment: There is only one field in that example that uses backslashes -- is that the _only field in the whole file_ that has this problem? That field is also blank -- will that field _always_ be blank as shown in the example? **What specific problem is this situation currently giving you?**

Comment: @AdityaVerma, can you please mention the structure (datatypes of all columns/ddl script) of table redshifttable in the question. This might help more.